# modify wordpress Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, megamenu

I'm trying to modify the nav walker menu in order to have a mega menu on every li with 'has-mega-menu' class and the default menu on every other li

```
class Mega_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            $location = 'mega_menu';
            $css_class = 'has-mega-menu';
            $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
            $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';
            $atts = array();
            $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
            $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
            $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
            $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

            if ( is_array($item->classes) && in_array( $css_class, $item->classes) ){
                   if ( isset( $locations[ 'mega_menu' ] ) ) {
                    $menu = get_term( $locations[ 'mega_menu' ], 'nav_menu' );
                    if ( $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->name ) ) {
                        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                          $output .= "<a href=\"{$item->url}\">{$item->title}</a>";
                                if ( is_active_sidebar( 'mega-menu-widget-area-' . $item->ID ) ) {
                                  $output .= "<div id=\"mega-menu-{$item->ID}\" class=\"mega-menu\">";
                                        dynamic_sidebar( 'mega-menu-widget-area-' . $item->ID );
                                  $output .="</div>";
                                }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );
            $attributes = '';
            foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                    }
            }
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

            $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );
            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

the problem is that i have in my mega menu all the item of my menu

Comment: You need to add a control on your menus that will toggle the megamenu change. I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dingo-d/d4baf91adbcdf2c22161) that adds a megamenu but the control to do so is triggered by javascript which means that you'll need to first set the menu to megamenu, and then refresh the page to show the select dropdown for it. I still haven't gotten around to include this in the menues themselves (php), it's on my to do list. Feel free to look how I did it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I remember almost sorting this issue before, so I revisited it and I solved it. I hope it will help anybody who reads this.

The gist can be found here: [click to gist](https://gist.github.com/dingo-d/d4baf91adbcdf2c22161).

First your menu walker. I've added a walker that has sidebars in the menu and megamenu, so that you can even put your sidebars (widgets) in the megamenu if you want (neat trick :D)

```
<?php

// Allow HTML descriptions in WordPress Menu
remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );
function my_plugin_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
    if ( isset( $menu_item->post_type ) ) {
        if ( 'nav_menu_item' == $menu_item->post_type ) {
            $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', $menu_item->post_content );
        }
    }

    return $menu_item;
}

add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'my_plugin_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );


class my_custom_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

public function display_element($el, &$children, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output){
    $id = $this->db_fields['id'];

    if(isset($children[$el->$id])){
        $el->classes[] = 'has_children';
    }

    parent::display_element($el, $children, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
}


// add classes to ul sub-menus
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'navi',
        ( $display_depth ==1 ? 'first' : '' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'navi' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}
// add main/sub classes to li's and links
 function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    static $is_first;
    $is_first++;
    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : '' ),
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'navi' : '' ),
        ( $is_first ==1 ? 'menu-first' : '' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );
    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    $post_meta_array = get_post_meta($item->ID);
    $is_megamenu = $post_meta_array['_menu_item_megamenu'][0];
    $is_mega_menu = ($is_megamenu !== '') ? true : false;
    $use_desc = (strpos($class_names, 'use_desc') !== false) ? true : false;
    $no_title = (strpos($class_names, 'no_title') !== false) ? true : false;
    $is_sidebar = (strpos($class_names, 'menu_sidebar') !== false) ? true : false;

    if(!$is_mega_menu){
        $class_names .= ' normal_menu_item';
    } else{
        $class_names .= ' '.$is_megamenu;
    }

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li a id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';
    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="' . (($item->url[0] == "#" && !is_front_page()) ? esc_url(home_url('/')) : '') . esc_attr($item->url) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ' class="menu-link '.((strpos($item->url,'#') === false) ? '' : 'scroll').' ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

    $html_output = ($use_desc) ? '<div class="description_menu_item">'.$item->description.'</div>' : '';

    if ($is_sidebar) {
        ob_start();
        dynamic_sidebar($item->description);
        $sidebar_html = ob_get_clean();

        $sidebar_output = '<div class="sidebar_menu_item">'.$sidebar_html.'</div>';

        $item_output = $sidebar_output;

    } else{
        $item_output = (!$no_title) ? '<a ' . $attributes . '><span>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . '</span></a>'. $html_output : $html_output;
    }
    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ).( ($is_mega_menu) ? '<div class="sf-mega"><div class="sf-mega-inner clearfix">':'');
}

function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    $is_mega_menu = (strpos($class_names,'mega') !== false) ? true : false;

    $output .= (($is_mega_menu)?'</div></div>':'') . "</li>\n";
}

}

// Megamenu in menu. Modified original file by Weston Ruter on https://gist.github.com/westonruter/3802459

add_action( 'init', array( 'my_custom_Nav_Menu_Item_Custom_Fields', 'setup' ) );

class my_custom_Nav_Menu_Item_Custom_Fields {

    static $options = array(
            'item' => '
                <div class="additional-menu-field-{name} {container_class}">
                <style scoped>
                    .additional-menu-field-megamenu{display:inline-block;}
                </style>
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-{name}-{id}">{label}</label>
                    <div class="megamenu">
                        <select name="{name}" id="select-mega-menu-{id}">
                            <option value="">Default Standard Menu</option>
                            <option value="{mega1}">Mega Menu - Single Column</option>
                            <option value="{mega2}">Mega Menu - 2 Columns</option>
                            <option value="{mega3}">Mega Menu - 3 Columns</option>
                            <option value="{mega4}">Mega Menu - 4 Columns</option>
                            <option value="{mega5}">Mega Menu - 5 Columns</option>
                            <option value="{mega6}">Mega Menu - 6 Columns</option>
                            <option value="{mega7}">Mega Menu - 7 Columns</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="{input_type}" id="edit-menu-item-{name}-{id}" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-{name}" name="menu-item-{name}[{id}]" value="{value}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            ',
        );

    static function setup() {
        self::$options['fields'] = array(
            'megamenu' => array(
                'name'            => 'megamenu',
                'label'           => esc_html__('Mega Menu', 'my_custom'),
                'container_class' => 'menu-megamenu',
                'input_type'      => 'hidden',
            ),
        );

        add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', function () {
            return 'my_custom_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit';
        });
        add_filter( 'my_custom_nav_menu_item_additional_fields', array( __CLASS__, '_add_fields' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( __CLASS__, '_save_post' ) );
    }

    static function get_fields_schema() {
        $schema = array();
        foreach(self::$options['fields'] as $name => $field) {
            if (empty($field['name'])) {
                $field['name'] = $name;
            }
            $schema[] = $field;
        }
        return $schema;
    }

    static function get_menu_item_postmeta_key($name) {
        return '_menu_item_' . $name;
    }

    /**
     * Inject the
     * @hook {action} save_post
     */
    static function _add_fields($new_fields, $item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        $schema = self::get_fields_schema($item->ID);
        foreach($schema as $field) {
            $field['value'] = get_post_meta($item->ID, self::get_menu_item_postmeta_key($field['name']), true);
            $field['id'] = $item->ID;
            //Tried to implement selected() here but was unsuccesfull, so I just left it like this, the mega fields aren't necessary, you can add them by hand
            $field['mega1'] = 'mega1';
            $field['mega2'] = 'mega2';
            $field['mega3'] = 'mega3';
            $field['mega4'] = 'mega4';
            $field['mega5'] = 'mega5';
            $field['mega6'] = 'mega6';
            $field['mega7'] = 'mega7';
            $new_fields .= str_replace(
                array_map(function($key){ return '{' . $key . '}'; }, array_keys($field)),
                array_values(array_map('esc_attr', $field)),
                self::$options['item']
            );
        }
        return $new_fields;
    }
    /**
     * Save the newly submitted fields
     * @hook {action} save_post
     */
    static function _save_post($post_id) {
        if (get_post_type($post_id) !== 'nav_menu_item') {
            return;
        }
        $fields_schema = self::get_fields_schema($post_id);
        foreach($fields_schema as $field_schema) {
            $form_field_name = 'menu-item-' . $field_schema['name'];
            if (isset($_POST[$form_field_name][$post_id])) {
                $key = self::get_menu_item_postmeta_key($field_schema['name']);
                $value = stripslashes($_POST[$form_field_name][$post_id]);
                update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php';
class my_custom_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit extends Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        $item_output = '';
        parent::start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
        $new_fields = apply_filters( 'my_custom_nav_menu_item_additional_fields', '', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        // Inject $new_fields before: <div class="menu-item-actions description-wide submitbox">
        if ($new_fields) {
            $item_output = preg_replace('/(?=<div[^>]+class="[^"]*submitbox)/', $new_fields, $item_output);
        }
        $output .= $item_output;
    }
}

//Sidebars in Menu

if ( !class_exists('sidebars_custom_menu')) {
    class sidebars_custom_menu {
        public function add_nav_menu_meta_boxes() {
            add_meta_box(
                'sidebar_menu_add',
                esc_html__('Add Sidebar', 'my_custom'),
                array( $this, 'nav_menu_link'),
                'nav-menus',
                'side',
                'low'
            );
        }

        public function nav_menu_link() {?>
            <div id="posttype-sidebars" class="posttypediv">
                <div id="tabs-panel-sidebars" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-active">
                    <ul id ="sidebars-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                        <?php
                        $i = -1;
                        foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) {
                            ob_start();
                            dynamic_sidebar($sidebar['id']);
                            $sidebar_html = ob_get_clean();
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <label class="menu-item-title">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-item-checkbox" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>][menu-item-object-id]" value="<?php echo $sidebar['id']; ?>"> <?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['name'] ); ?>
                                </label>
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-type" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>][menu-item-type]" value="custom">
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-attr-title" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>][menu-item-attr-title]" value="<?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['name'] ); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-title" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>][menu-item-title]" value="&nbsp;" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-url" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>][menu-item-url]" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-classes" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>][menu-item-classes]" value="menu_sidebar">
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-description" name="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>][menu-item-description]" value="<?php echo $sidebar['id']; ?>">
                            </li>
                            <?php
                            $i --;
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p class="button-controls">
                    <span class="list-controls">
                        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'nav-menus.php?page-tab=all&amp;selectall=1#posttype-sidebars' ); ?>" class="select-all"><?php esc_html_e('Select All', 'my_custom'); ?></a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="add-to-menu">
                        <input type="submit" class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu right" value="<?php esc_html_e('Add to Menu', 'my_custom');?>" name="add-post-type-menu-item" id="submit-posttype-sidebars">
                        <span class="spinner"></span>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
}

$custom_nav = new sidebars_custom_menu;

add_action('admin_init', array($custom_nav, 'add_nav_menu_meta_boxes'));
```

I won't go into the details about what's what (I'll leave that for my site later on), but just trust me, it works :D

Also you need a bit of JS help with the `change` events and options staying selected. Add this in a separate .js file that you'll include only on `nav-menus.php` page

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).on('change', '.megamenu select', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().val( $this.val() );
    });

    $('.megamenu select').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var selected = $this.next().val();
        var option_length = $this.find('option').length;

        for (var i = 0; i < option_length; i++) {
            if ($($this.find('option')[i]).val() == selected) {
                $($this.find('option')[i]).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        }

    });

});
```

This will give you something like this:

[image]

Now the 'only' thing I didn't include here is the css. But you can figure it out, not that hard. Basically the key thing is this:

```
.mega1 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 100%;}
.mega2 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 50%;}
.mega3 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 33.33333333333333%;}
.mega4 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 25%;}
.mega5 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 20%;}
.mega6 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 16.66666666666667%;}
.mega7 .sf-mega-inner > ul > li{width: 14.28571428571429%;}
```

This will set the widths of your `li` s inside the megamenu menu. You'll also need to set them either as `float:left` (easy way), or as `inline-block` elements with `vertical-align:top` and a `font-size:0` on the parent `ul` element (so that they fit).

Hope this helps out with the megamenu problem :D

Comment: I had a question about your mega menu if i want something like that : http://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/preview4.jpg with widget . I choose "mega menu 4 colum" for what's new item. i add my custom menu with "default standard menu" to my sidebar and then i add this sidebar to my menu when it's finish i play with the css of aside.widget_nav_menu  ul.menu in order to have the mega menu. Am i right or do you know an easier way to have this mega menu with sidebar menu ?

Comment: First you create a regular menu, with a dummy link 'What's new'. Then in this link you put 3 dummy sublinks: Home, Home, Home and one sidebar (Related Categories). In the 3 sublinks you can put your other links (you can even add your own class to make it look bolder in some cases), and you should get the desired look. The only thing you need to do is to style them properly, and they should look like that. I worked on a theme that can do all that [click](http://preview.ab-themes.com/spiral/).

Comment: This time i just need to a mega menu to a site but i  look the themes you made in ab-themes there look good and i keep it in mind when i want to change my site theme :) . I'm also new in using wordpress and i search some tutorial or trick for improving a wordpress theme i see you had a personal site http://denis-zoljom.from.hr/ did you plan to add some tutorial there ? And finally i can't upvote it need 15 reputations and i only got 7 : /

Comment: I am currently in the process of creating another site dedicated to the tutorials for wordpress [madebydenis.com](http://madebydenis.com). It should be out next month once I finish designing it and putting some content up :)